# Sitecore Powershell Extensions not returning field source value

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm trying to write a simple Powershell script that finds all `General Link` fields and outputs the value of their `Source` field.

```
$fields = Get-ChildItem -Path "master://sitecore/templates/user defined" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Template field" -and $_.Type -eq "General Link" }

foreach ($field in $fields) {
    Write-Host "Name: $($field.Name)"
    Write-Host "Source: $($field.Source)"
    Write-Host
}
```

Whenever I run it, however, the value from the `Source` field is empty for all returned items.

[image: Returned list of fields and empty sources]

I've confirmed that it is populated in at least some of the cases, but it never shows up in the report. I've tried several variations to get the value, too:

```
$fields | Show-ListView -property `
    @{ Name="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.Path} },
    @{ Name="Source"; Expression={$_.Source} },
    @{ Name="Source With Quotes"; Expression={$_."Source"} }
```

## Versions

- Sitecore version: 8.1 Update 3
- Sitecore PowerShell Extensions version: 5.0.0.42513

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `Source` property on `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` class.

You need to get `Source` field value e.g. like this:

```
foreach ($field in $fields) {
    Write-Host "Name: $($field.Name)"
    Write-Host "Source: $($field._.Source.Value)"
    Write-Host
}
```

Comment: This example is making use of a custom object SPE adds to the item. You can use `_` or `PSFields` to get typed properties.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `Source` field is of type `Template Field Source`, which seems to not automatically emit a value if you simply access the field directly on the item (`$field.Source`).

Instead, you must get the field and get the value from that field:

```
$field.Fields['Source'].Value
```